# Read headers (only) of a large CSV file in (browser) javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, csv, http

I am trying to read CSV headers of a large file stored on AWS S3 using Javascript. I am wondering if there is a way of just reading the header only without reading the entire file.

I have tried using d3.csv and http.get but both of these load the entire file. Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you want to read the headers of your columns, and not the data in it (from what I understood from your question, which, to be honest, is misleading), know that you won't be able to do so on the client side. 

Since you have to request the file to process it, it means it will request the entire file through the network, which I'm sure you don't want to happen. 

Instead, you should write a script on AWS (I'm not familiar with it so I can't help) to do that. I suggest you to use the correct tags for your question, now that you know that !

Comment: Agree I am looking for the columns of the csv file not the request headers.. @trichetriche i think your explanation makes sense, i might have to go down a server script route. This must be a common problem, wondering if there are any other approach

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use of range byte in your header request to read partial of the file

[S3 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#ExampleGetRangeRequestHeaders) Range: bytes=0-12000

EDITED Working example.

```
fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/aml-sample-data/banking.csv", {
   headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/byteranges',
    'range': 'bytes=0-512'
   },
  })
.then(response => {
    var reader = response.body.getReader().read().then(data => {
  var binArray = data.value;
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < binArray.length; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(binArray[i]));
  }

   var result = str.search(/\n/);
   if (result > -1) {
   var header = str.substring(0, result);
   console.log('found' , header);

     return response.text();

  } else {
return response.text();
  }

    });

})
.then(response => {
    var result = response.search(/\n/);
    if (result > -1) {
  var header = response.substring(0, result);
  console.log('from last request', header);
    }
});
```

**For test don't forget to turn off cors checking in your Chrome browser**

```
chrome.exe  --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user- 
data-dir="D:\temp"
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that he has to know the exact length of the line ?

Comment: Yes he need to keep pulling range of byte till he reach `"\n"` with offset

Comment: That doesn't sound very practical ... Instead he could use a Linux command like `head` to get the first line, and echo it in a file ?

Comment: Yes you can do that in many ways, but he is using HTTP request to S3 storage, I don't know if he there is away to run a remote shell command S3